# Running Hadoop in multi-node cluster not working

Tags: java, hadoop

I had a HDFS installed and working on 3 computers .then i tried to add 5 more PCs to the existing Cluster but after doing so .when i tried to start hadoop on Master node i got this error mentioned below.

```
[hduser@dellnode1 ~]$ start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.out
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:216)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
dellnode3.pictlibrary: datanode running as process 4856. Stop it first.
dellnode1.pictlibrary: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.out
dellnode2.pictlibrary: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dellnode2.pictlibrary.out
dellnode1.pictlibrary: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-dellnode1.pictlibrary.out
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-dellnode1.pictlibrary.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:216)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
dellnode3.pictlibrary: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-dellnode3.pictlibrary.out
dellnode1.pictlibrary: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-dellnode1.pictlibrary.out
dellnode2.pictlibrary: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-dellnode2.pictlibrary.out
```

All pc's running Fedora 17

Comment: It clearly says `FileNotFoundException` and `Permission denied` and tells you the paths. Can't you resolve that for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the log file manually with something like

```
sudo touch  /usr/local/hadoop/bin/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.log
```

If your path is

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.log
```

better fix as I wrote in the first line.

Then change the file's permissions:

```
sudo chmod 750 /usr/local/hadoop/bin/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dellnode1.pictlibrary.log
```

and try again. It should work this time ;-)